# htmlspecialchars ENT_NOQUOTES is not working

Tags: php, security, htmlspecialchars

I tried to use `ENT_NOQUOTES` with `htmlspecialchars` becuase I want to allow `single quote` and `double quote`.But it is not working.

Here is my line of code

```
$post=htmlspecialchars($post,ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

I also tried

```
$post=htmlspecialchars($post,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

But none of them worked.

Just wondering,will there be any security risk if I don't convert `quotes`?

Please help me out,if you can.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you dont convert quotes, it may create problem while inserting into DB

Comment: Show the value of `$post` please

Comment: here is `$post` output `Adidas Shoe&#39;s Shoe by :Adidas Shoe;Adidas Shoe [ ] \ ? | @ `.

Comment: It was for testing,that's why used junk.Sorry abt that.Used one `'` which converted to `&#39;`

Comment: What is the input value?

Comment: I tried, its working fine : `$post = "df&df<d'fgf";
echo htmlspecialchars($post,ENT_NOQUOTES);` . Output : `df&amp;df&lt;d'fgf` . Can you re-check the input string ? Tell us the exact input string for which you are facing issue (Not some junk string) ??

Comment: I am `fetching data` from database.I entered `Adidas Shoe's Shoe by :Adidas Shoe;Adidas Shoe [ ] \ ? | @ ` on form and got the above result.

Comment: where you are using `htmlspecialchars` before inserting into DB ? CAn you post some code ?? Your input string works fine : https://ideone.com/jdkxYg

Comment: I have just used `filter_input()` before inserting data into database.Is it causing any trouble?

Comment: So are you just trying to convert the above to a string with single quotes and output it to the screen for example? If so just use `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode` works too.But is it safe?I thinks using `filter_input` is the reason why `ENT_NOQUOTES` is not working

Comment: Well, if the data is already stored in the database using filter_input, it's already stored safely. Are you now fetching data, and want to display it properly?

Comment: Yes,And `htmlspecialchars_decode` is working fine.So,should I use that?

Comment: Yes, or html_entity_decode. See my answer

Comment: You shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars()` when inserting into a database; it's used for when you present it inside a web page.

Comment: I didn't use `htmlspecialchars()` before inserting into database.I used `filter_input` before inserting into database.But as I read from blogs,It is best to use `htmlspecialchars()` before output on screen,which doesn't give me user friendly output.So,if I use `htmlspecialchars_decode` or `html_entity_decode()`,will it be properly safe?

Comment: @Jack,Please have a look at my comment and get back to me,if possible because I'm very worried about my site security.Will decoding allow XSS attacks?Thanks

Comment: Using `htmlspecialchars_decode` for output is a bad idea.

Comment: When I filter the inputs,it saved in database as encrypted.Like `&#39;` for `apostrope`.So,how can I show `'` to user using `htmlspecialchars` after I fetch data.I'm really worried and confused

Comment: @Ja͢ck Your reply will really be appreciated.

Comment: Has anyone pointed out that it's `ENT_QUOTES` not `ENT_NOQUOTES` yet? Because that's the actual bug OP is running into.